# Separate equations on separate lines

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm new to laTex and I've started writing my first article with it.
I have a number of equations to display, and I'm stuck at the most fundamental level. All the equations that I type are displayed in line, as shown in the image. Could someone please tell me what mistake I'm making here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{force}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}
m_1*a_1 = F1
m_2*a_2 = F2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thank You
[image: equations are displayed in line]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment `equation` can only display one equation line. Very likely you want to use `gather` or `align` instead, the latter can be used to align the `=`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{force}
\maketitle
\noindent
Example for \texttt{gather}:
\begin{gather}
m_1*a_1 = F1\\
m_2*a_2 = F2
\end{gather}
Example for \texttt{align}:
\begin{align}
m_1*a_1 &= F1\\
m_2*a_2 &= F2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank You very much for the swift reply. It worked, and it gave me an understanding of how this works. 
Thank You very much

Answer (score 4):

`amsmath` has a number of environments intended for presentation of multiple or multi-line equations.  take a look at the documentation: `texdoc amsmath`.

there is also an online tool if that's more convenient: http://www.texdoc.net/